# Scala Circe. Encoder type Any

Tags: json, scala, circe

I am trying encode `class ResponseResult` to json

```
case class ResponseResult (var Code : Int,
                 var Message: String,
                 var Data: Any )

var json = ResponseResult(1, "2", List(3,4,5)).asJson
```

I get an error **could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[ResponseResult]**

Then I create encoder

```
object ResponseResult {
    implicit val encodeResult: Encoder[ResponseResult] =
        Encoder.forProduct3[ResponseResult, Int, String, Any]("Code", "Message", "Data") {
            case ResponseResult(c, m, d) => (c, m, d.toString)
        }
}
```

I get an error **could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: Encoder[Any]**

This is my full code

```
import io.circe.Encoder
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

object a {
  case class ResponseResult (var Code : Int,
                             var Message: String,
                             var Data: Any )
  object ResponseResult {
    implicit val encodeResult: Encoder[ResponseResult] =
      Encoder .forProduct3[ResponseResult, Int, String, Any]("Code", "Message", "Data") {
        case ResponseResult(c, m, d) => (c, m, d.toString)
      }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var json = ResponseResult(1, "2", List(3,4,5)).asJson
  }
}
```

Anyone can show me How to encode `class ResponseResult`.
Thank you

Comment: You don't have a reason to use `var`s here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you cannot have Codec for `Any` type, simple as that.

If you want to pass some value there, serialize it and be able to deserialize it later, you have to assume some type. You can defer this assumption by using type parameter:

```
case class ResponseResult[Data](Code : Int,
                                Message: String,
                                Data: Data)
```

and requiring existence of encoder for this type parameter:

```
object ResponseResult {
  implicit def encodeResult[Data: Encoder]: Encoder[ResponseResult[Data]] =
    Encoder.forProduct3[ResponseResult[Data], Int, String, Data]("Code", "Message", "Data") {
      case ResponseResult(c, m, d) => (c, m, d)
    }
}
```

then you will be able to serialize data like you want

```
// inferred to ResponseResult[List[Int]]
val response = ResponseResult(1, "2", List(3,4,5))

// and Circe can generate codec for List[Int] automatically
// so it can now generate codec for ResponseResult[List[Int]]
val json = response.asJson
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use Json type for Data.

```scala
case class ResponseResult (var Code : Int,
                 var Message: String,
                 var Data: io.circe.Json )
```

so you can pass anything to Data, null too.